# Camel download files

Tags: download, ftp, apache-camel

I have maybe a stupid question but how I can to download files from ftp server.
I use the route

> .from("ftp:/test@localhost:21/?password=test") .to("file:/d:\\test")

I have the error : can not store null body. Why ? I read several examples Where is my error? Thanks

**EDIT**

I use the route :

> .from("direct:xx")
>   .from("ftp://test@localhost:21/?password=test")
>   .to("file://d:\inbox");

And I have the error :

org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot write null body to file: d:\inbox\xxxxxxx
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:237)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
.from("ftp://test@localhost:21/?password=test").to("file://d:\\test")
```

I am pretty sure about the from part. But the to part you might have to change a little bit(wrt '/') because I have not worked on windows

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: firstly you are consuming from ftp server on path `/`. Make sure this is correct.

Comment: yes It's correct. I have 3 files.
I call my route by `producer.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:xx", null, "a", 10);`

Comment: make sure you have files present in `/` directory on ftp and you have permissions to read the file. From the error it seems that it cannot read anything from the path specified. hence it says `Cannot write null body`

Comment: I have 3 files and I tested with filezilla. I can see and download files

Comment: try with one file first by giving something like this `....:21/fileName?....`. Before that on the ftp server where are these files i mean what is the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter 'allowNullBody=true' to your **TO** file endpoint

> to("file://d:\test?allowNullBody=true")

---

If you go deep into source code as state in `org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:237)`, you will see the related GenericFileOperationFailedException happens when

1. In Body of exchange is null
2. allowNullBody is set to false

By default, allowNullBody in File producer is 'false' as state in [Camel File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html). You need to change it to 'true' to allow storage of empty files.